# 3 points divide each side of a triangle into a constant ratio. Find the ratio of the new triangle's area to the old triangle's area

Tags: geometry

'Given a triangle ABC, points P, Q, and R are taken on BC, CA, AB such that BP:PC= CQ:QA = AR:RB = m:n. Prove that the area of PQR: area of ABC = m^3 + n^3 : (m+n)^3'

I have tried to apply similar triangles to the problem, but there don't seem to be any, and I can't see how the cubic terms appear. Please help.

Comment: what is $$m,n$$ here?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify. I've changed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If $\frac{AR}{AB}=\frac{BP}{BC}=\frac{CQ}{CA}=\lambda$ and $[ABC]=\Delta$, we have

$$ [ARQ]=[BPR]=[CQP] = \lambda(1-\lambda) \Delta, $$
hence
$$ [PQR] = \left[1-3\lambda(1-\lambda)\right]\Delta.$$